# Pass bash script arguments in double quotes to php cli script

Tags: bash, command-line, php, quoting

I am trying to pass arguments to a bash script and then to a php script, I have literally looked at 30+ links, and tried over a dozen examples, and I for whatever reason have not been able to get the following to work, I am seriously frustrated, any help is so very much appreciated.

For the sake of this question, lets say I have the following bash script (test.sh)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

/usr/bin/php test.php $@
```

and I have the following PHP script (test.php)

```
<?php

print_r($argv);
```

and I am trying to execute the bash script with the following arguments

```
./test.sh hello world "how are you"
```

the results of the above is the following

```
Array
(
    [0] => test.php
    [1] => hello
    [2] => world
    [3] => how
    [4] => are
    [5] => you
)
```

and I am looking for the results to be

```
Array
(
    [0] => test.php
    [1] => hello
    [2] => world
    [3] => how are you
)
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated... I am banging my head against the desk....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would have been enough to have a look at the "QUOTING" block in bash's man page... (to find a pointer to the PARAMETERS block where it is explained)

```
/usr/bin/php test.php "$@"
```

Comment: hrmmmmm, ok, lol, let me rephrase the question, that absolutely worked in this example, however, in the actual php cli script, I am using it is not working... editing now

Comment: ooook, it looks like this is not a problem with the examples, or even the php, the root of this problem lies within http://github.com/jeffreyroberts/sub it appears... which is a heavily modified fork of http://github.com/37signals/sub ... Thank you all for your help, at least the problem has been identified, I wish I had just ran the damn example scripts lol.... when I wrap $@ in double quotes using the sub <sub-command> arg1 "arg2a arg2b", the php script was returning an array with 2 elements, the full script path, and all of the arguments, I will dig into sub and see whats up, thanks again!